# Pure css solution to setting percentage width of div for dynamic contained text

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to achieve is quite simple with javascript, but I need a pure css solution if possible.

I have a div 438px X 348px. I am generating a dynamic list inside this div. The list elements have a height of 30px each and are set to list-inline and float-left. I have set the li width to (33% - padding) and text-overflow to ellipsis. So the list appears as 3 uniform columns and when the text is longer than width of li elements it gets truncated and shows "..." at the end. Now I want the li elements to have 33.3% or 66.6% or 100% automatically according to the text contained. Is there a pure css solution to this?

This is the javascript code code I tried.

```
var listWidth = 432;
var oneColWidth = (33.3 * listWidth / 100) - 25;
var twoColWidth = (66.6 * listWidth / 100) - 25;
var threeColWidth = (99.9 * listWidth / 100) - 25;

$('#value_list_' + optionID + ' li').each(function() {
    var listItemWidth = $(this).find('div').width();

    if(listItemWidth < oneColWidth) {
        $(this).width(oneColWidth);
    }
    else if(listItemWidth < twoColWidth) {
        $(this).width(twoColWidth);
    }
    else {
        $(this).width(threeColWidth);
    }
});
```

It is not working exactly as I want, but I need some similar logic. Here is a screenshot of what I have achieved with this code.

[image]

Comment: What did you try so far? Please share your code.

Comment: Share your Code See:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I have updated the question with the present code and a screenshot.

Comment: Please share your Html or working code in codepen or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have used the flex and tried the following: You can know about the flex via this [Flex link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Here the default layout is 3 column but if there is an overflow the flex pushes the next item in the next row...

```css
.parent {
  width: 438px;
  height: 348px;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <ul>
    <li>content 1</li>
    <li>content 2 with extra characters</li>
    <li>content 3</li>
    <li>content 4</li>
    <li>content 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This solution was perfect for the question I asked. I missed out on adding some details to my question, like how one column will be empty for certain places where there are two 2 consecutive list elements that span two columns, or similar cases. None the less this solution works perfect for whatever i mentioned in my question. Thank you for the solution.

Comment: Also, my design requirements have now changed and I am using width 100% for all the list items so it is a scrollable list.